# Scala system command working differently from commandline

Tags: scala

I'm executing this command in terminal and it works just fine:

```
curl -d "sentence=Jack sold the car to Jenny" austen.cs.illinois.edu:8082/parse
```

On the other hand executing things don't seem to be working in Scala:

```
import sys.process._
val output = s"""curl -d \"sentence=Jack sold the car to Jenny\" austen.cs.illinois.edu:8082/parse""".!!
println(output.split("\t"))
```

which outputs:

```
[error]   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
[error]                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
[error] 
[error]   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: sold
[error] curl: (6) Could not resolve host: the
[error] 
[error]   0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: car
[error] curl: (6) Could not resolve host: to
[error] curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Jenny"
[error] 
[error] 100    37  100    23  100    14    153     93 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   153
```

Thoughts why I see different behaviors here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per documentation of [`scala.sys.process`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.x/scala/sys/process/index.html), execution of a string assumes that arguments are separated by spaces, and there is no way to escape embedded spaces.

> **What to Run and How**
>
> ...
>
> Implicitly, each process is created either out of a String, with arguments separated by spaces -- no escaping of spaces is possible -- or out of a scala.collection.Seq, where the first element represents the command name, and the remaining elements are arguments to it. In this latter case, arguments may contain spaces.

Your `curl` request body argument contains embedded spaces, so it is assuming that they are multiple space-delimited arguments.  Since there is no escaping possible, you would have to execute it as a `Seq` instead, with each element explicitly specifying where there is a new argument and where there is a single argument with embedded spaces.

```
val output = Seq("curl", "-d", "sentence=Jack sold the car to Jenny", "austen.cs.illinois.edu:8082/parse").!!
```